# Pivot Rows to Column in SQL without Aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm looking to pivot multiple rows into columns. But when i use Max or Min in Pivot, its returning only one row. I want to display all the rows. Can any one help with this ?

From:
[image]

To:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select object_key,
       max(case when name = 'OBJECT_NAME' then value end) as object_name,
       max(case when name = 'Start Time' then value end) as start_time,
       max(case when name = 'End Time' then value end) as end_time,
       max(case when name = 'row_count' then value end) as row_count,
       max(case when name = 'Execution Time' then value end) as execution_time
from t
group by object_key;
```

I'm not sure why you specify "no aggregation" in the question.

If you really have an aversion to aggregation use can use `join`s:

```
select ton.object_key, ton.value as object_name,
       ts.value as start_time, te3.value as end_time,
       . . 
from t ton on
     t ts
     on ton.object_key = ts.object_key join
     t te
     on ton.object_key = t3.ojbect_key. join
     . . . ;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon !
I was just thinking hard on pivot but failed to see case when option available :)
This worked as i expected. Thanks once again